# http site doesn't forward to https on IE

Tags: linux, apache, internet-explorer, https, protocols

My website has an SSL cert (example url: https://subdomain.example.com).  Under Apache it's set up for both port 80 and port 443.  So under the following configuration, anyone who goes to http://subdomain.example.com is sent to https://subdomain.example.com .  But for visits from Internet Explorer, the redirect doesn't happen.  Instead, http visits get a "Internet Explorer cannot display the web page." with a list of client-side solutions to try.

Any ideas on how to fix IE?--that is make it go from http to https like the rest do?

Here is my config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/somewebroot
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/somewebroot
     ServerName subdomain.example.com
    #   SSL CERTS HERE
</VirtualHost>
```

*Tested IE8, IE9 beta

**EDIT**

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:///%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Where is the relevant redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look's like you have a extra slash in your rewrite rule, 3 slashes instead of 2 after https.

/Viktor

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... this seems to work for all browsers:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```